# how open a database with cfs, cfx ,and gen extension file?

Tags: java, .net, database, lucene, cfs

I need open database of a software that use this three extension: cfs, cfx, and gen. I google and understood this is a Lucene index file but I dont have any java or lucene knowledge.
Please show me simplest way to open and read text of this file.[image of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6s5l.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) can help

From the github page

> Luke is the GUI tool for introspecting your Lucene / Solr / Elasticsearch index.

I don't exaclty know from where you got that database files but as far as lucene (or solr) is concerned [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) does the job of opening and viewing *Lucene* index.

As for the files in the screenshot

`.cfs` Compound File: An optional "virtual" file consisting of all the other index files for systems that frequently run out of file handles.

`segments.gen segments_3` Segments File:    Stores information about a commit point

Taken from: http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene54/package-summary.html#package_description